# Is it Possible to have the sharepoint content sorting rules automatically update as new metadata tags are generated?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sorting, drop-off-library

I'm trying to set up a content organizer for a SharePoint site so that it creates folders based off the metadata given. Specifically in two different categories. I created two taxonomy sets, one for workers which is not editable (the staff doesn't change much), and other for projects which is updateable. When someone goes to upload a file associated with a project they can pick a worker and then either pick an associated project name or add a new one. No Problems so far.

The issue is that I would like the content organizer to sort them into files based on these two tags.

So a file for each worker, and then sub files for each worker project.

So within the library it would go *All data --> Timmy --> Lifelong project*

Think I managed to figure that out with the content organizer rules as well (not sure if it will create the branching structure properly but I can figure that out later)

The issue becomes when someone adds new metadata for a new project. If someone uploads a file not associated with any project and adds a new tag for the project metadata it won't update the rules for the content sorter automatically. Is there any way I can make this happen for each new tag added so I don't have to constantly update all the tags manually?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.